# No space left on device in spite partition is not 100%

Tags: linux, centos, partition, device, disk-space-utilization

I am trying to do the following on my Linux machine CentOS release 5.8

```
 cd /var/APPstoreldap/Home
 touch test
 touch: cannot touch `test': No space left on device
```

so I verified the partition disk space capacity in order to understand if  /var/APPstoreldap/Home partition reached to 100%

But what I get is that partition **is only 51%**

```
 df -h | grep APPstoreldap

 /dev/mapper/vg07-var  5.0G  2.7G  2.0G  51% /var/APPstoreldap/Home
```

so please advice why I get

```
 No space left on device
```

What could be the problem here?

.

other test:

```
df -i| grep APPstoreldap

/dev/mapper/vg07-var  655360  655360       0  100% /var/APPstoreldap/Home
```

Comment: What is the output of `df -i| grep APPstoreldap`?

Comment: see the update question.... last command

Comment: but what the meaning of df -i?

Comment: At the risk of sounding like I'm saying RTFM, well... do a `man df` and find out.

Comment: `$ man df` <--- always read the man page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have exhausted the number of inodes available in your filesystem. It's likely that you have a directory somewhere with a crap-ton of small files, hopefully some type of temporary files that can be deleted without issue. You'll need to find that directory and asses whether or not the files are critical.

Beyond that, you'll need to consider creating a new filesystem with a larger number of inodes and copying data over there.